# Access Data class property while using Generic Type parameter <T> in runtime [Kotlin]

Tags: kotlin, generics, type-parameter, data-class, kotlin-reified-type-parameters

I'm trying to return a property/value from Data class by checking type parameter

Data Class :

```
data class SystemConfiguration(
    val systemName: String,
    val fields: List<String>
)
```

Abstract class :

```
abstract class ConfigurationLoader<out T> {
    abstract val clazz: Class<out T>

    private fun getAssociateAttribute(file: T): String{
        return when(clazz){
            SystemConfiguration::class.java -> file.systemName // Line causing error
            // If its another Data class, I should return value from that data class
            else -> ""
        }
    }

    open fun loadConfigurations(): Map<String, T>{

        val map = Paths.get(configurationFolderPath, filePath).toFile().walkTopDown().filter { it.isFile }.map {
            val x = ionSystem.loader.load(it)[0]
            ionValueMapper.readValue<List<T>>(x.toString())
        }.flatten().associateBy { getAssociateAttribute(it) }
    }
}

inline fun <reified T: Any> javaClasstype(): Class<T> {
    return T::class.java
}
```

Sub class

```
class ServiceConfigurationLoader (
    override val clazz: Class<SystemConfiguration> = javaClasstype()

): ConfigurationLoader<SystemConfiguration>()
```

I'm getting an exception "e: Unresolved reference: systemName". Not able to access values inside data class while we use type parameter

If i use like this(directly mentioning data class name), I'm able to access the values

```
private fun getAssociateAttribute(file: SystemConfiguration): String{
        return when(clazz){
            SystemConfiguration::class.java -> file.systemName
            else -> ""
        }
    }
```

Could someone help me out here to access the value using Type paramater in Kotlin?

Thanks in Advance !!

I have tried using reified keyword as well. Still getting the same issue. I'm expecting to access the value using Type paramater

Comment: Can you explain why you have made it `ConfigurationLoader<out T>` instead of `ConfigurationLoader<T>`?

Comment: I'm also interested in what you are doing in `// Do something`. This might turn out to be an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info) depending on that. Would you mind showing what you do in that?

Comment: You would need to manually cast `file` to SystemConfiguration before accessing its properties. This way of checking the class type is too roundabout for smart casting to do it automatically.

Comment: Hi @Sweeper, Tried adding <out T> to make clazz as covariant. But I'm getting the same issue even if I use like ConfigurationLoader<T>. 

On //Do Something, I actually read a configuration file(ION) and assign it to a map. Added the code above.

Comment: Hi @Tenfour04 , I have other 5-6 data classes as well like SystemConfiguration. I don't know which class it will be in runtime. Is there a way to case without using Data class names like "SystemConfiguration" ?

Comment: Do you know all the possible classes it could be? Why not solve this with inheritance or a sealed interface?